# Overvoltage protection Piezo Harvester

Tags: ac, zener, energy-harvesting, over-voltage-protection

I have a piezo harvester, capable of creating spikes of 50+Volts. My harvesting circuit which will be connected to the harvester output, has a maximum rating of 20Volts. Therefore I need some kind of overvoltage protection.
I considered adding 2 zener diodes rated at 20V as the below schematic indicates.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f8t9WV.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

If the piezo voltage is under 20V, it is my understanding that no current will flow through the diodes and all the power will be transferred to whatever is connected to Vout (battery, load, etc).
If however the voltage rises over 20V, then the diodes will start conducting, trying to keep a constant voltage of 20V across Vout. My question is, if I do not put a resistor, I believe that the diodes will be fried. If I however place a resistor in series with the piezo, I will be having power losses on the resistor, even during normal (Vpiezo<20V) operation.

Are the above correct? If so, what would be the easiest solution for overvoltage protection for my piezo harvester?

Comment: I guarantee the spikes of the Piezo are far higher than 50V, but very short. Think about why you see none of that, and you'll have the solution to your problem that, unlike your ESD diodes, doesn't absorb a significant part of the energy your Piezo crystal provides.

Comment: Still, wouldn't a resistor waste power all the time? I understand that the spikes are short, but whatever power the piezo produces, some will be lost in the resistor. Considering this is an energy harvesting application, this does not sound like the best idea.

Comment: The effect is not resistive.

Comment: @MarcusMüller Are you talking about the internal resistance of the piezo? I understand that, what I cannot figure out is why shorting the piezo output (after that 20Volts of course) will not cause damage to the piezo.

Comment: internal resistance is a resistive effect, so, no I'm not talking about that: you're oversimplifying your cabling when you think it's only resistive. what other passive linear components do you know than resistors.